# lines in an inverted barplot in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to add a line using the argument `lines` to a barplot in R, however my barplot is inverted `horiz = TRUE`, and when I write `lines` the line is not inverted.

For example:

```
x = c(4,7,8,6,9,10,12,6,5,8,14,10,6,8,5,3)

barplot(x, horiz = TRUE, space = 0)

lines(x, col="red")
```

What I want is:

[image: What I want]

And what I'm obtaining is:

[image: Second]

Comment: Firstly, you need to get rid of the `=` in `barplot` so your code runs. Secondly, show us what you're trying to do to get the lines that is not working.

Comment: I just edited, I showed the plot I want, ignore the position of the axes, I inverted (what I want) as an image because I don't know how, So i just want to inverted the line too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a base R solution, you need to provide a proper x and y to `lines`:

```
lines(y = seq_along(x) - 1, x = x, col="red")
```

Note that these axes are not switched, and y refers to the vertical axis.

[image]

Comment: What if I want to plot x vs counts?

Comment: ' lines(y = seq_along(x$counts) - 1, x = x$counts, col="red")' this works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `ggplot2`, this is not too hard. Notes:

- You'll likely want to put `x` in a `data.frame` to make it easier to reference, and you'll need to make a sequence to make your vertical axis (here with `seq_along`).
- The `aes` is a little weird because variable `x` is mapped to `y`, but since it's supplying heights, that's what you want.
- You'll also need to specify `stat = 'identity'` in `geom_bar` so it doesn't try to make a histogram.
- At the end, `coord_flip` flips the axes for the whole plot.

All told:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x = seq_along(x), y = x)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
    geom_line(colour = 'red') + 
    coord_flip()
```

[image: sideways barplot with red line]

Comment: Thanks that helps me a lot. What if I tried to plot x vs frequency? counts in y vs x inverted too, like you just did

Comment: Change the `stat`s and the `aes` mappings, but it's pretty much the same: `ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x = x)) + 
    geom_bar() + 
    geom_line(colour = 'red', stat = 'count') + 
    coord_flip()`